# Cloning a bitlocked HDD to SSD

Tags: windows, backup, hard-disk, disk-image, ssd

I would like to upgrade my corporate laptop to an SSD drive without going through the tedious process of getting our IT team to do it.
Can I make an exact copy of my bitlocked system and trick my laptop into thinking nothing has happened?

Can anyone recommend any cheap or free software that can do this?

Comment: Whilst it may seem like a tedious task for your IT, it is probably best to consult them - after all, they're paid for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is [not a recommended solution](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/755032-how-to-clone-a-bitlocker-encrypted-hdd) to clone an encrypted drive using an imaging software which does sector by sector copy without decrypting it first as there could be issues with size of drive, firmware issues with SSD drives, TPM module storing the id of the drive etc.

Most drive cloning software like Macrium Reflect, Acronis TrueImage and Farstone Drive Clone can clone a BitLocker encrypted drive provided you have [admin rights](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f86a006e-ca76-4309-8515-03151a206628/how-to-move-full-os-bitlocker-partition-to-larger-hard-drive?forum=w7itproinstall) on the machine. It does the cloning by after you disable BitLocker on the volume which writes the encryption key to the drive and then copy the the data to the new drive and then turn on BitLocker.

Most big companies don't give admin rights so you may be out of luck if your company is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

That's a yes and no answer.  Yes, Casper Secure Disc 4.2 can clone and even resize a bitlocker locked drive to another drive while you're working in windows.  I've used the trial version which does not allow resizing, and it cloned a bitlockered Win10 x64 drive to another SSD.  I could boot the clone and it asked for the bitlocker PIN just like the source, and worked fine.  Now the no part: 129 smackeroos.  You're call on whether or not it's worth it.  You can use AOMEI sector by sector backup, and it'll clone the Bitlocker driver to another drive but the target will be UNencrypted, although bootable.  You then need to encrypt it. Sooo, worth 129 bucks to ya?